# C# datagridview unicode character encoding

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, datagridview, character

I cannot sort out the following problem:
I use a datagridview column to tell the user if the item of that row has already been processed. A little unicode icon should suffice, I thought, so I went for U+2174 (check mark) and U+2715 (cross) to achieve what I wanted. For the datatable...

```
row["Done"] = (listProcessed.Contains(file.FullName)) ? "\u2714" : "\u2715";
```

It works well in debug and release mode on my development machine, but it fails on a Windows XP virtual machine. On that one, only narrow squares are shown, just as if it didn't know the characters.

I read somewhere that it might be due to line endings, so I tried to apply *TrimEnd(null)* to the strings, but that did not help.

Is there a way to make this work on Windows XP? What exactly is going wrong?

thx i.a.

Comment: I am using MS VS2008 and .NET 3.5 if that is of any importance to the question.

Comment: Probably Windows XP uses a font that does not contain those two characters - you should try with different characters or try changing the font used by the form.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Did both to no avail (see comment for SLaks's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the Windows XP machine is using a font that does not contain those characters.

Use charmap to see if you can find a font which does.  (try Arial Unicode MS)

Comment: Oh, you are probably right, it is a font problem. Arial Unicode MS does indeed contain those characters, but is not necessarily available on the client machines. Therefore, it would have to be a standard Windows font. Wingdings contains the characters according to *charmap*, but fails to reproduce said characters on notepad and wordpad on the Windows XP machine. Does that mean I should resort to making images and use those instead of unicode characters? I thought it should be rather easy, but now it appears like characters are a can of worms.

Comment: Ok, I redesigned it to use a System.Drawing.Bitmap of the character, so I don't have to fear any incompatibilties. I'm still sad that unicode characters can cause such problems, I thought there was a standard. Thanks for pointing out charmap to me.

Comment: @FranzB.: There is a standard.  However, not all fonts contain all characters.

Comment: @FranzB: ..Wingdings is not Unicode - you can use it, but the cross and checkmark are charactes 0xFB and 0xFC respectively.